# How to remove duplicates from a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

My current df looks like this:

```
    IDnumber     Subid      Subsubid     Date        Originaldataindicator
      a            1          x           2006           NaN
      a            1          x           2007           NaN
      a            1          x           2008           NaN
      a            1          x           2008           1
```

The originaldataindicator is the result of the fact that some of these observations were created to get all three years for each IDnumber, while some existed in the original dataset. 
What I want to achieve is to drop the duplicates and prefarably keep the original data. Note that the originaldataindicator will not always be the last observation. 
To solve this I first sort on Idnumber Date Originaldataindicator

However when I use:

```
  df=df.drop_duplicates(subset=['IDnumber', 'Subid', 'Subsubid', 'Date'])
```

Nothing happens and I still observe the duplicate.

```
  df=df.drop_duplicates(subset=['IDnumber', 'Subid', 'Subsubid', 'Date'], inplace=True)
```

gives me an empty dataframe.

Am I misinterpreting what drop_duplicates does ?

Just to avoid confusion, this is what I want:

```
    IDnumber     Subid      Subsubid     Date        Originaldataindicator
      a            1          x           2006           NaN
      a            1          x           2007           NaN
      a            1          x           2008           1
```

The data includes thousands of these ID's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and then use parameter `keep=first` of [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
print df
  IDnumber  Subid Subsubid  Date  Originaldataindicator
0        a      1        x  2006                    NaN
1        a      1        x  2007                    NaN
2        a      1        x  2008                    NaN
3        a      1        x  2008                      1
4        a      1        x  2008                    NaN

df = df.groupby(['IDnumber', 'Subid', 'Subsubid', 'Date'])
              .apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('Originaldataindicator')).reset_index(drop=True)
print df
  IDnumber  Subid Subsubid  Date  Originaldataindicator
0        a      1        x  2006                    NaN
1        a      1        x  2007                    NaN
2        a      1        x  2008                      1
3        a      1        x  2008                    NaN
4        a      1        x  2008                    NaN

df1=df.drop_duplicates(subset=['IDnumber', 'Subid', 'Subsubid', 'Date'], keep='first')
print df1
  IDnumber  Subid Subsubid  Date  Originaldataindicator
0        a      1        x  2006                    NaN
1        a      1        x  2007                    NaN
2        a      1        x  2008                      1
```

Or use `inplace`:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['IDnumber','Subid','Subsubid','Date'], keep='first', inplace=True)
print df
  IDnumber  Subid Subsubid  Date  Originaldataindicator
0        a      1        x  2006                    NaN
1        a      1        x  2007                    NaN
2        a      1        x  2008                      1
```

If column `Originaldataindicator` have multiple values use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) (maybe ther can be add all columns `IDnumber`,`Subid`,`Subsubid`,`Date`) and [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html):

```
print df
  IDnumber  Subid Subsubid  Date  Originaldataindicator
0        a      1        x  2006                    NaN
1        a      1        x  2007                    NaN
2        a      1        x  2008                    NaN
3        a      1        x  2008                      1
4        a      1        x  2008                      1

print df[~((df.duplicated('Date',keep=False))&~(pd.notnull(df['Originaldataindicator'])))]
  IDnumber  Subid Subsubid  Date  Originaldataindicator
0        a      1        x  2006                    NaN
1        a      1        x  2007                    NaN
3        a      1        x  2008                      1
4        a      1        x  2008                      1
```

Explaining conditions:

```
print df.duplicated('Date', keep=False)
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
dtype: bool

print (pd.isnull(df['Originaldataindicator']))
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
Name: Originaldataindicator, dtype: bool

print ~((df.duplicated('Date', keep=False)) & (pd.isnull(df['Originaldataindicator'])))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thank you, an update to Python 3.5 and making sure my original and new data objects matched in type finished the job.

Answer (score 4):

Consider this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 3, 3], 'b': [1, 2, None, 1, None]})
```

Then

```
>>> df.sort_values(by=['a', 'b']).groupby(df.a).first()[['b']].reset_index()
    a   b
0   1   1
1   2   2
2   3   1
```

Sorts the items by first `a`, then `b` (thus pushing the `None` values in each group last), then selects the first item per group.

I believe you can modify this to the specifics of your problem.